# xcode - Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, debugging

I get this error when the ViewController loads.
I don't know, what I can do
[image: EXC_BAD_ACCESS]

The loadDataFromDb function is this

```
func loadDataFromDb() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Chats")
    daten = self.context!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as! [Model]
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I googled that error but nothing helped me

Comment: The address for the error is 0x0 which implies a nil address for the cell. Check you gave the cell prototype the correct reuse identifier which should be "Cell" based on your code. It is case sensitive. You should also use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` rather than the version you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:) returns an optional that might be nil.

Your force casting to `UITableViewCell`, by using `as!` makes it so that the nil gets casted to `UITableViewCell` and you end up calling a method on nil, which leads to the exception.

Try unwrapping the cell, by using `if let`  before using it or better yet use [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String,
                          forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> AnyObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:) , which doesn't return an optional.

Also as a whole, try staying away from `!` and refrain from using it, unless you absolutely have to.

Edit:

Here's one way to do it

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell {

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Text"

        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't know, how the if let method would look like. Which ! do you mean? How would a correct code look like at this point?

Comment: If I use as instead of as! I get "'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'UITableViewCell'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

Comment: I've updated my answer with one possible way to do it.

Comment: Does this -     `daten = self.context!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as! [Model]`  populate the `daten` var? Also do all objects in `[Model]` have a username?

Comment: I deleted the app from the simulator - now it es working with your code

Comment: No not. But I see that `daten` does not have the correct input, but yes `daten = self.context!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as! [Model]` populates the `daten` var.

Comment: but I can't find out why. If i launch the app the first time this table is empty - I then fill the `daten` var and come back to the tableview that crashes and it shows up right with the correct usernames - if i click one username another view controller comes up - if I then go back it crashes

Comment: when I launch the app `daten` is `[]`. when the table shows up the first time with `daten`not empty it is `[<Model: 0x7fef0a5cf360> (entity: Chats; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://0514DEAF-D3CF-43AF-B26A-DC8048B04587/Chats/p1> ; data: {
    messages = nil;
    username = Chris;
})]`

Comment: When it crashes `daten` is `[<Model: 0x7ff54b0519a0> (entity: Chats; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://0514DEAF-D3CF-43AF-B26A-DC8048B04587/Chats/p1> ; data: <fault>), <Model: 0x7ff54b051e80> (entity: Chats; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://0514DEAF-D3CF-43AF-B26A-DC8048B04587/Chats/p2> ; data: <fault>), <Messages: 0x7ff54b054200> (entity: Messages; id: 0xd0000000000c0002 <x-coredata://0514DEAF-D3CF-43AF-B26A-DC8048B04587/Messages/p3> ; data: <fault>)]`